# After clicking on the update button, I want to insert the updated dataset into a new dataset while deleting it from the old one

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Here is the code I have so far. The tables are filled correctly. But how can I insert the Edited row to the Valid table and then deleting it from the Edit table? I don't have a primary key as the tables were imported from an Excel sheet that only contains 3 columns Name, Email and Mobile.

[image: What I'm trying to do]

This is what I have so far:

```js
 protected void GridView4_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName=="Update")
        {
            DataSet EditT = new DataSet();
            DataSet ValidT = new DataSet();
            if (Session["Edit"] != null)
            {
                EditT = (DataSet)Session["Edit"];
            }
            if (Session["Valid"] != null)
            {
                ValidT = (DataSet)Session["Valid"];
            }
           
            
            DataTable dtEdit = EditT.Tables[0];
            DataTable dtValid = ValidT.Tables[0];
        }
    }
```

and if you want to see how I uploaded the Excel sheet here is the code:

```js
    protected void UploadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = string.Empty;
        if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {

            try
            {
                string[] allowFile = { ".xls", ".xlsx" };
                string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                bool isVaidFile = allowFile.Contains(fileExt);
                if (!isVaidFile)
                {
                    MessageLbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    MessageLbl.Text = "Must be an Excel file";
                }
                else
                {
                    int fileSize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                    if (fileSize <= 1048576)
                    {
                        filename = Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName));
                        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadExcel/") + filename);
                        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/UploadExcel/") + filename;
                        OleDbConnection con = null;
                        if (fileExt == ".xls")
                        {
                            con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";");
                        }
                        else if (fileExt == ".xlsx")
                        {
                            con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";");
                        }
                        con.Open();
                        DataTable dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                        string getExcelSheetName = dt.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                        string ExcelCommandText = @" SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + @"]";
                        string ValidExcelCommandText = @"SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + @"] where ((Email like '%@_%.com') and (Name is not null) and not ( ISNUMERIC(Mobile) = 0))";
                        string EditExcelCommandText = @" SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + @"] where Email not like '%@_%.com' or Email is null or Name is null or Mobile is null or Mobile not like '^[[:digit:]]+$'";
                        OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand(ExcelCommandText, con);
                        OleDbCommand EditExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand(EditExcelCommandText, con);
                        OleDbCommand ValidExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand(ValidExcelCommandText, con);
                        OleDbDataAdapter EditAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(EditExcelCommand);
                        OleDbDataAdapter ValidAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ValidExcelCommand);
                        OleDbDataAdapter ExcelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelCommand);
                        DataSet ExcelDataSet = new DataSet();
                        DataSet EditDataSet = new DataSet();
                        DataSet ValidDataset = new DataSet();
                        Session["Edit"] = EditDataSet;
                        Session["Valid"] = ValidDataset;
                       
                        EditAdapter.Fill(EditDataSet);
                        ValidAdapter.Fill(ValidDataset);
                        ExcelAdapter.Fill(ExcelDataSet);
                        con.Close();
                        GridView5.DataSource = ValidDataset;
                        GridView4.DataSource = EditDataSet;
                        GridView3.DataSource = ExcelDataSet;
                        GridView3.DataBind();
                        GridView4.DataBind();
                        GridView5.DataBind();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageLbl.Text = "Attachment file size should not be greater than 1 MB";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageLbl.Text = "Error occurred while uploading file. " + ex.Message;
            }
        
        }
        else
        {
            MessageLbl.Text = "";
        }
       
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on the assumption that the columns are identical in the Data Tables, you can identify the row using its index. You can copy the values of the row into a new row in the second table. You can't just add the row as it belongs to dtEdit and will throw an error unless you use .ItemArray.

```
        DataSet EditT = new DataSet();
        DataSet ValidT = new DataSet();

        DataRow row;

        DataTable dtEdit = EditT.Tables[0];
        DataTable dtValid = ValidT.Tables[0];
        //Assuming columns match exactly;

        int rowIndex = 0; //Find the index of the row that is clicked.

        row = dtEdit.Rows[rowIndex];

        dtValid.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray); //NB: Must use .ItemArray as row belongs to dtEdit.
        dtEdit.Rows[rowIndex].Delete();
```

Comment: What's happening with this is that dtValidTable is adding the row without it being edited and dtEditTable is emptying the row of it's values but is not being removed so i'm just replacing the row with invalid information with an empty one
Also the row updated even is being fired but I have nothing written in it so it gives me : "The GridView 'GridView4' fired event RowUpdating which wasn't handled."

Comment: Basically I'm currently just stuck with     dtEdit     not being updated

Comment: I'm trying this piece of code:

 `foreach (DataRow rows in row)
                {
                    rows["Name"] = ((TextBox)GridView4.FindControl("textBox1")).Text;
                    rows["Email"] = ((TextBox)GridView4.FindControl("textBox2")).Text;
                    rows["Mobile"] = ((TextBox)GridView4.FindControl("textBox3")).Text;
                }
                dtValid.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);`

Comment: But it won't take the foreach statement, it doesn't accept it